# как уменьшить простой блок кода if else

Tags: javascript, dom

Есть страничка с высотой 4600 пикселей и есть блок кода которое при скролле плавно приближает элементов справа налево или наоборот, но код получился слишком длинным так, как страничка длинная. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно его как-то уменьшить?

```
var withAp = document.querySelector('.withAp');
var textSkills = document.querySelector(".text-skills")
var goaltext = document.querySelector('.goal-text')

window.onscroll = function() {
    //Определяем наше текущее место на странице
    var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    //Задаём значение от куда до куда работают свойства
    if (scrolled < 100) {
        withAp.style.marginRight = '0';
        withAp.style.opacity = '0.1';
    }
    if (scrolled > 100) { 
        withAp.style.marginRight = '30px';
        withAp.style.opacity = '0.2';
    }
    if (scrolled > 200) { 
        withAp.style.marginRight = '50px';
        withAp.style.opacity = '0.2';
    }
    if (scrolled > 300) {
        withAp.style.marginRight = '80px';
        withAp.style.opacity = '0.4';
    }
    if (scrolled > 400) {
        withAp.style.marginRight = '100px';
        withAp.style.opacity = '0.5';
    }
    if (scrolled > 500) {
        withAp.style.marginRight = '120px';
        withAp.style.opacity = '0.6';
    }
    if (scrolled > 600) {
        withAp.style.marginRight = '150px';
        withAp.style.opacity = '0.7';
    }
    if (scrolled > 700) {
        withAp.style.marginRight = '180px';
        withAp.style.opacity = '0.8';
    }
    if (scrolled > 800) { 
        withAp.style.marginRight = '200px';
        withAp.style.opacity = '1';
    }
    //===============text skills==============================
    if (scrolled < 700) {
        textSkills.style.marginRight = "0px";
        textSkills.style.opacity = "0";
    }
    if (scrolled > 800) {
        textSkills.style.marginRight = "20px";
        textSkills.style.opacity = "0.3";
    }
    if (scrolled > 900) {
        textSkills.style.marginRight = "30px";
        textSkills.style.opacity = "0.5";
    }
    if (scrolled > 1000) {
        textSkills.style.marginRight = "40px";
        textSkills.style.opacity = "0.6";
    }
    if (scrolled > 1100) {
        textSkills.style.marginRight = "50px";
        textSkills.style.opacity = "0.7";
    }
    if (scrolled > 1200) {
        textSkills.style.marginRight = "60px";
        textSkills.style.opacity = "0.8";
    }
    if (scrolled > 1300) {
        textSkills.style.marginRight = "70px";
        textSkills.style.opacity = "1";
    }
    //=====================goal-text===================
    if (scrolled < 1800) {
        goaltext.style.marginLeft = "-80px";
        goaltext.style.opacity = "0";
    }
    if (scrolled > 1700) {
        goaltext.style.marginLeft = "0px";
        goaltext.style.opacity = "0.2";
    }
    if (scrolled > 1800) {
        goaltext.style.marginLeft = "10px";
        goaltext.style.opacity = "0.4";
    }
    if (scrolled > 1900) {
        goaltext.style.marginLeft = "30px";
        goaltext.style.opacity = "0.6";
    }
    if (scrolled > 2000) {
        goaltext.style.marginLeft = "40px";
        goaltext.style.opacity = "0.7";
    }
    if (scrolled > 2100) {
        goaltext.style.marginLeft = "50px";
        goaltext.style.opacity = "0.8";
    }
    if (scrolled > 2200) {
        goaltext.style.marginLeft = "60px";
        goaltext.style.opacity = "1";
    }
};
```

Comment: напишите функцию)

Comment: Если цифры связаны математически - то лучше в функцию, внутри которой вычислять по формуле, если не связаны - искать связь и выносить. А еще, есть некие подозрения...возможно имеется смысл делать `if(...){...}else if(...){...}` либо перейти к `switch...case`, либо внутри условия использовать двойное условие, чтобы был интервал, причем интервалы со строгими и нестрогими неравенствами, чтобы охватить весь диапазон. Как-то так...

Comment: Для приведённого кода разумнее определить статические массивы значений `margin` и `opacity`, и выбирать нужное по индексу, в качестве которого использовать результат целочисленного деления `scrolled` на 100.

Comment: Можно "смешаный" вариант, поставить тройное условие (100-800) а потом два (700-1300 и 1800-2200) внутри которых для marginLeft  и opacity  - формулу.

Comment: @Akina а как именно напишите код пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изначальный код содержит логические не точности.

Блок withAp дыра в точке 100. Приписал к первому диапазону.

Блоки text skills и goal-text не описал: логические ошибки в диапазонах.
< 700, >800 - А между?

< 1800, > 1700 - диапазоны пересекаются.

Для описания диапазонов использую обозначения:  [ - включительно, ( - не включительно

```
    var withAp = document.querySelector('.withAp');
    var textSkills = document.querySelector(".text-skills")
    var goaltext = document.querySelector('.goal-text')

    window.onscroll = function() {
        //Определяем наше текущее место на странице
        var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        //Задаём значение от куда до куда работают свойства
        scrolled = (scrolled-0.001) / 100 | 0; //-0.001 - для того что бы 200 попал в диапазон (100,200] и т.д. По факту получаем диапазон [100.001,200,001).
//Задаю массивы.
        var margin = ["0","30px","50px","80px","100px","120px","150px","180px","200px"];
        var opacity = ["0.1","0.2","0.2","0.4","0.5","0.6","0.7","0.8","1"];
//Само присвоение.
        withAp.style.marginRight = scrolled<1 ? margin[0] : (scrolled > 8 ? margin[8] : margin[scrolled]); //Если меньше 100, то margin[0], если больше 800, то margin[8].
        withAp.style.opacity = scrolled<1 ? opacity[0] : (scrolled > 8 ? opacity[8] : opacity[scrolled]); //аналогично.
//===============text skills==============================
//по аналогии
//=====================goal-text===================
//по аналогии
    };
```

Comment: Из доп. оптимизаций можно ещё margin делать +25 , и opacity +0.1

Comment: Не получится. Т.к. не линейная формула. Хотя если менять логику, то можно.

Comment: @Dan Irkutskiy спасибо большое и дай бог здоровье но подскажите где дыра в точке 100?и где логические ошибки <700 , >800?и если можно обьясните  этот алгоритм пожалуйста (scrolled-0.001) / 100 | 0;

Comment: Исходный код: "if (scrolled < 100) {" и "if (scrolled > 100) {". А что делать, если (scrolled == 100)?

Comment: В блоке text skills описано какие переменны использовать при scrolled < 700 и >800, но что делать если scrolled==750 например?

Comment: Алгоритм прост. scrolled целочисленно делю на 100. Т.е. все значения от 0 (не включительно) до 100  (включительно) будут равны 0. От 100 до 200 равны 1 и т.д. Далее создаю массивы с данными из исходного кода. Где Элемент массива 0 таков, что бы соответствовал условию <100. И далее присваиваю.

Comment: @Dan Irkutskiy спасибо огромное

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если вопрос решен - поставьте отметку на ответе.